# Как автоматически перевести инфоблок на другой язык в битрикс

Tags: php, битрикс

в интернете я нашёл мало информации об автопереводе динамического контента в битрикс, возможно я плохо искал. Цель такая - перевести инфоблок каталога с русского на английский и украинский язык. Локализация помогает с переводом статического контента, того что не вписываешь в инфоблоки. Я купил яндекс ключ переводчика для api перевода. В php и api я ещё к сожалению не силён, подскажите пожалуйста как лучше реализовать этот момент.

Answer (score 0):

В двух словах выполнение вашей задачи не описать. Вам нужен опытный программист, который через события или напрямую переведет ваш PREVIEW_TEXT в зависимости от выбранной локализации сайта пользователем.